# Attaching a recorded .caf file locatted in documents directory to mail iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, email, documents, mfmailcomposer, caf

I have files recorded by the user in the documents directory... displayed in a uitableview...

I placed this code in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath... Why doesn't this work?

```
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];

MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mailer addAttachmentData:audioData mimeType:@"audio/caf" fileName:fileName];
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in the debugger to make sure none of those references is nil?

Comment: yes... the debugger is blank... is it supposed to be?

Comment: So you don't know how to use the debugger? Learning to use it would be good! It shows you the values of all those references (paths, documentsDirectory, fileName, and so on) so you can see whether they are what you expect. Just walking through the code would probably have solved your problem. Otherwise you're sort of programming by guesswork...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the URL incorrectly. You need to use `fileURLWithPath`, not `URLWithString`.

Also, this:

```
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

Should be:

```
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

There is no need for the string format.

Last thing. Th file name passed to the `addAttachment` method should be just a file name, not a full pathname.

Comment: But then I get an error: ARC semantic issue... No known class method for selector 'fileURLWithString:'

Comment: Sorry, typo. That should be fileURLWithPath.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your fast reply! it is greatly appreciated!